# Disabling FKA SMTP Tweak, what are the consequences?

Tags: security, email, web-server

I was testing web application on the server it is meant to be finally deployed to and it was having issues sending emails. The error messages I was receiving lead me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47239212/2505109).

When I disabled the option "FKA SMTP Tweak" in WHM the emails started working as expected.

What I want to know is what are the wider security consequences with me disabling this option? Can I retain the protection it affords while still allowing my web app to send it's emails?

Answer (score 0):

Well - it lets other users send mails. With this setting in place, you're essentially forced to route all outgoing mails through exim (and you'd need to configure said webapp to send mails to it - bit fuzzy on that part).

The worst case scenario, presumably is that you get compromised, and some app *other* than the one you want sending emails can send emails